# Jquery Form Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using the following validation code on my web app

demo : http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html

is there any way to hide that popup thing after 10 second ?  now when you submit its keep displaying ....

these are the codes used for ceating that effect

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js 
http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/js/jquery.validationEngine.js

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
            jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();
        });

        /**
        *
        * @param {jqObject} the field where the validation applies
        * @param {Array[String]} validation rules for this field
        * @param {int} rule index
        * @param {Map} form options
        * @return an error string if validation failed
        */
        function checkHELLO(field, rules, i, options){
            if (field.val() != "HELLO") {
                // this allows to use i18 for the error msgs
                return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: its too large i will post those code links

Comment: you can hide the all formErrorContent class and line class and do this like as under

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code put on above header tag

```
<script>

    setInterval(function() {
        $(".formError").parent('.formErrorOuter').remove();
        $(".formError").remove();
},  2000);
</script>
```

try it.it's work

Comment: yes its working :) and it will be great if you can add fade out effect for hiding :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var t = setInterval(function() {
   //alert('b');
   $(".formErrorContent").hide();
   $(".line1").hide();$(".line2").hide();$(".line3").hide();$(".line4").hide();$(".line5").hide();
   $(".line6").hide();$(".line7").hide();$(".line8").hide();$(".line9").hide();$(".line10").hide();
   },8000);
```